# Thousands .htaccess redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website with 1500 posts that need to be redirected.

I have conflicting categories due to which I am unable to redirect complete category. Current structure is as below:

**Cars category**

```
Redirect 301 /blog/videos/top-5-cars http://www.example.net/articles/cars/videos/top-5-cars
```

**Holiday Category**

```
Redirect 301 /blog/videos/exotic-holiday-locations http://www.example.net/articles/holiday/videos/exotic-holiday-locations
```

Since **/blog/videos/** fall under both Cars & Holiday category I am unable to redirect as below

```
Redirect 301 /blog/videos /articles/holiday/videos
```

This is the case with 1500 articles. Is it wise to write redirect rule for 1500 articles in .htaccess? Is there a better workaround?

Please suggest.

Comment: Well, is there *any* pattern you can establish? Perhaps rewrite to a PHP file which can more "intelligently" figure out how to rewrite the URL and have *it* do the redirection?

Comment: Current approach we have taken is to redirect user to the correct URL from 404 page but that is leading to major count of 404 on the website and thus looking for .htaccess solution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Redirect` directive with `RedirectMatch` directive that can match using regex to give you precise matching.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/videos/top-5-cars/?$ /articles/cars/videos/top-5-cars

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/videos/exotic-holiday-locations/?$ /articles/holiday/videos/exotic-holiday-locations

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/videos/?$ /articles/holiday/videos
```